XのAPIから返されるユーザーのアクセストークンの有効期限について
Q1.XのAPIから返されるユーザーのアクセストークンに有効期限はありますか？
Q2.この辺りは何の仕様で決まるのですか？ X？ OAuth？
Q3.XのAPIから返されるユーザーのアクセストークンが変わるのはどんな時ですか？　ユーザーがアプリ連携解除後、再度連携した時？
質問背景
TwitterOAuthのOAuthで下記コード実行した結果取得できるデータ内容が、どんな時に変更されるか知りたい
Example
$access_token = $connection->oauth("oauth/access_token", ["oauth_verifier" => "nMznkpFRTMCuNMsmALzel9FgPlmWQDWg"]);


"twitter oauth access token expire" で Google 検索すると、以下の FAQ がヒットします。
FAQ | Docs | Twitter Developer Platform

アクセストークンの有効期限を教えてください。
アクセストークンは明示的に期限切れとなることはありません。ユーザーがTwitterのアカウント設定でアプリケーションを明示的に取り消すか、Twitterがアプリケーションを停止すると、アクセストークンは無効となります。アプリケーションが停止されると、停止された旨がTwitterアプリのダッシュボードに表示されます。

